# CakePHP $this->set() don't works in Pages Controller

Tags: php, cakephp

I am developing with CakePHP and this is my Page Controller:

```
<?php
class PagesController extends AppController
{
    var $name = 'Pages';
    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Session');
    var $uses = array();

    function display()
    {
        $path = func_get_args();

        $count = count($path);
        if (!$count) {
            $this->redirect('/');
        }
        $page = $subpage = $title_for_layout = null;

        if (!empty($path[0])) {
            $page = $path[0];
        }
        if (!empty($path[1])) {
            $subpage = $path[1];
        }
        if (!empty($path[$count - 1])) {
            $title_for_layout = Inflector::humanize($path[$count - 1]);
        }
        $this->set(compact('page', 'subpage', 'title_for_layout'));
        $this->render(implode('/', $path));

        $this->loadModel('Curso', 2);

        $select = $this->Curso->query("SELECT * FROM cursos ORDER BY `cursos`.`created` DESC  LIMIT 2;");
        $this->set('cursos', $select);
        //$this->set($select);

    }
}
```

But `$this->set('cursos', $select);` don't works, this is the error:

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: cursos[APP/views/pages/home.ctp, line 36].
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Be warned that PagesController is for static pages, i.e. pages that don't require data. Consider that you'll be running this query for each static page in your site. If you need to do a database fetch, it's better to create a `CursosController`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you're setting it after the `$this->render()` call. The render call is when the view gets loaded and executed.

Comment: move the loadModel and set( 'cursos', .. ) calls to before the $this->render( ) call and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Both method worked for me, i have already used.

First Method solution for: (Because the render call is before your set statement)

```
<?php
class PagesController extends AppController
{
    var $name = 'Pages';
    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Session');
    var $uses = array();

    function display()
    {
        $this->loadModel('Curso', 2);

        $select = $this->Curso->query("SELECT * FROM cursos ORDER BY `cursos`.`created` DESC  LIMIT 2;");
        $this->set('cursos', $select);

        //Now put your rest of code

    }
}
?>
```

Second Method

```
<?php
class PagesController extends AppController
{
    var $name = 'Pages';
    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Session');
    var $uses = array();

    function display()
    {

        //put your  code

        $this->loadModel('Curso', 2);

        $select = $this->Curso->query("SELECT * FROM cursos ORDER BY `cursos`.`created` DESC  LIMIT 2;");
        $this->set('cursos', $select);

        try {
            $this->render(implode('/', $path));
        }
        catch (MissingViewException $e) {
            if (Configure::read('debug')) {
                throw $e;
            }
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }


    }
}
?>
```